# How To Scrape this embbed public tableau

Tags: tableau-api, screen-scraping

I am very new to the world of scraping data off of websites and am at a lost on how to grab data off of a website that is using Tableau Public

https://www.ccee.org.br/web/guest/precos/painel-precos

[Tabela de Preços](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyzxj.png)

Comment: scrapy-playwright will be your best friend to complete this job

Comment: Why bother screen scraping when they give you a download button that will give you the data in a csv? Tableau is notoriously difficult to screen scrape.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We can use the link in Data.world to build a Web data connector that can be used by Tableau to read data LIVE. I have done this for many of my clients earlier in a completely non-commercial way